# wmi impersonation on remote computer as currently logon user

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access, impersonation

I have created mvc application. It's an intranet website. users login with windows authentication. After some certain progress i need to connect from webserver to client machine to trigger some wmi function. Everything works i can connect their wmi and trigger actions with my service account ( which is administrator on client computer )

My problem is the wmi context which i connect is always my administrator account's context. This is not what i want because i need to run this as currently logon user on the remote machine.

So. i need to login to remote machine with my admin account and run function as current user account. Is it possible ? or its not possible because of security of windows.

This is how i connect to remote computer

```
    ManagementScope wmiScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + remoteHost + wmiNameSpace);
wmiScope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
wmiScope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
ManagementPath wmiClass = new ManagementPath(wmiClassName);
ManagementClass wmiObject = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, wmiClass, null);
return wmiObject;
```

and this is how i trigger function

```
  ManagementClass wmiConnection = clientConnection.ConnectRemoteWMI(remote, @"\ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK", "CCM_ClientUtilities");
            ManagementBaseObject parameters = wmiConnection.GetMethodParameters(policyType);
            ManagementBaseObject result = wmiConnection.InvokeMethod(policyType, parameters, null);
```

Comment: WMI code please

Comment: Hello i edited my post. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer. However, you should have all the information you need here

[Connecting to WMI Remotely with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703458(v=vs.85).aspx)

In short you will need create a system [ManagementScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Note**  `System.Management` was the original .NET namespace used to access
>   WMI; however, the APIs in this namespace generally are slower and do
>   not scale as well relative to their more modern
>   `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` counterparts.

However

1. Create a `ManagementScope` object, using the name of the computer and the WMI path, and connect to your target with a call to `ManagementScope.Connect()`.
2. If you connect to a remote computer in a different domain or using a different user name and password, then you must use a [`ConnectionOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) object in the call to the `ManagementScope`.

   - Check out the it it takes a username and password [ConnectionOptions Constructor (String, String, SecureString, String, ImpersonationLevel, AuthenticationLevel, Boolean, ManagementNamedValueCollection, TimeSpan)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549781(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The `ConnectionOptions` contains properties for describing the
>   Authentication, Impersonation, username, password, and other
>   connection options.

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

// options takes more arguments, you need to read up on what you want

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2", options);
scope.Connect();

ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ObjectGetOptions o = new ObjectGetOptions(null, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass(scope, path, o);
...
```

> Generally speaking, it is recommended that you set your Impersonation
>   level to Impersonate unless explicitly needed otherwise

---

**Additional reading**

[Connecting to WMI Remotely with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703458(v=vs.85).aspx)

[ManagementScope Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ConnectionOptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ObjectGetOptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.objectgetoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ManagementPath Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ManagementClass Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Disclaimer** : You will have to read about these topics and work out what you need in your situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i was reading most of them but i'm confused about how to connect to machine with admin credentials and after that make impersonation

Comment: dont connect with admin credentials, call this locally call the remote machine, and use the user credentials as the user name and password

Comment: @Cozdemir you need to use  `ConnectionOptions`

Comment: atcually i dont have user's username and password. And the problem is even i had i cannot connect from server machine to client's machine because the client credentials does not have permission connect to remote wmi.  Is there some solution like : with my admin credentials i delegate client account ( like i give him admin powers on client machine for a while ) and he connects to remote machine as himself but with admin rights so he will have rights to connect to remote machine and run wmi functions

Comment: Yeah i must admit this is a littel convoluted, the only thing i can think of is, to write a wcf service, host it ware you need it, and only allow access to do certain things